# pt-archiver and foreign keys?

Tags: mysql, mariadb, percona, archive, percona-toolkit

How does pt-archiver handle foreign keys?

Does it archive associated data? (seems not but the documentation is not very clear to me)

And if not, how could one perform an archive of a table with all its associated data from other tables also being archived?

The [documentation](https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-toolkit/2.1/pt-archiver.html#extending) for custom module/plugin says that we can achieve this

*before_delete(row => @row)
This method is called for each row just before it is deleted. This applies only to --source. This is a good place for you to handle dependencies, such as deleting things that are foreign-keyed to the row you are about to delete. You could also use this to recursively archive all dependent tables.*

....

*before_insert(row => @row)
This method is called for each row just before it is inserted. This applies only to --dest. You could use this to insert the row into multiple tables, perhaps with an ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE clause to build summary tables in a data warehouse.*

but not how one can achieve this

Any experiences with this toll for this kind of of usecase?